# Get all properties including extention from its super class in swift2.0

Tags: ios, swift, properties, superclass, mirror

How can I got all properties including extends from its super class in swift2.0?
I try this:

`Mirror(reflecting: self)`

But only got properties itself, not include its super class's.

Comment: try  Mirror(reflecting: super)

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900604/swift-2-0-get-mirrored-superclass-properties.

Comment: @Martin R Great, thanks.