# How iterate through all properties of different classes in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

Let's say I have one parent class called Car with some properties and one method which actually does nothing.

```
class Car {
    var brandName : String
    var yearOfCreation : Int
    var color : String
    var numberOfDoors : Int

    func manipulateWithCar() {
    }

    init(brandName : String, yearOfCreation : Int, color : String, numberOfDoors : Int) {
        self.brandName = brandName
        self.yearOfCreation = yearOfCreation
        self.color = color
        self.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors
    }
}
```

And I have two child classes called SportCar and TankerCar. They have their unique properties and also the method from parent class is overridden and now it does something.

```
class SportCar : Car {
    var turbo : Bool
    var nitrousOxideEngine : Bool

    override func manipulateWithCar() {
        print("Putting turbo on your car...")
        turbo = true
    }

    init(brandName: String, yearOfCreation: Int, color: String, numberOfDoors: Int, turbo : Bool, nitrousOxideEngine : Bool) {
        self.turbo = turbo
        self.nitrousOxideEngine = nitrousOxideEngine
        super.init(brandName: brandName, yearOfCreation: yearOfCreation, color: color, numberOfDoors: numberOfDoors)
    }
}
```

And also there is one enum for the method. This is not important but you just want to keep it as in the homework.

```
enum TankerForm {
    case cilindrical
    case quadratic
}

class TankerCar : Car{
    var tankerFilledSize : Int
    var tankerForm : TankerForm

    init(brandName : String, yearOfCreation : Int,
         color : String, numberOfDoors : Int, tankerVolum : Int, tankerForm : TankerForm) {
        self.tankerForm = tankerForm
        self.tankerFilledSize = tankerVolum
        super.init(brandName: brandName, yearOfCreation: yearOfCreation, color: color, numberOfDoors: numberOfDoors)
    }

    override func manipulateWithCar() {
        print("Loading 200 gallon of oil")
        tankerFilledSize = 200
    }
}
```

Creating some objects...

```
var kia = Car(brandName: "Rio", yearOfCreation: 2015, color: "Green", 
numberOfDoors: 4)

var toyota = Car(brandName: "Corolla", yearOfCreation: 2015, color: 
"Red", numberOfDoors: 4)

var lamborgini = SportCar(brandName: "Aventador", yearOfCreation: 2018, 
color: "Black", numberOfDoors: 2, turbo: false, nitrousOxideEngine: 
false)

var mazeratti = SportCar(brandName: "Ghibli", yearOfCreation: 2017, 
color: "Red", numberOfDoors: 4, turbo: true, nitrousOxideEngine: false)

var kamaz = TankerCar(brandName: "Kamaz", yearOfCreation: 2007, color: 
"Yellow", numberOfDoors: 2, tankerVolum: 0, tankerForm: .cilindrical)

var belaz = TankerCar(brandName: "Belaz", yearOfCreation: 2003, color: 
"White", numberOfDoors: 2, tankerVolum: 0, tankerForm: .quadratic)
```

Creating arrays with objects...

```
var carrsArray : [Car] = [kia, toyota]
var sportCarsArray : [SportCar] = [lamborgini, mazeratti]
var tankerCarsArray : [TankerCar] = [kamaz, belaz]
```

And printing all the properties for Car class objects using for loop...

```
for value in carrsArray {
    print("This car is \(value.brandName)")
    print("The color is \(value.color)")
    print("The car has \(value.numberOfDoors) doors")
    print("The year of creation is \(value.yearOfCreation)")
    print(" ")
}
```

Printing all the properties for SportCar class objects using for loop...

```
for value in sportCarsArray {
    print("This car is \(value.brandName)")
    print("The color is \(value.color)")
    print("The car has \(value.numberOfDoors) doors")
    print("The year of creation is \(value.yearOfCreation)")
    if value.nitrousOxideEngine == true {
        print("This car has Nitrous Oxide Engine")
    } else {
         print("There is no Nitrous Oxide Engine on this car.")
    }
    if value.turbo == true {
        print("This car has turbo")
    } else {
        print("There is no turbo in this car.")
    }
    print(" ")
}
```

Printing all the properties for TankerCar class objects using for loop...

```
for value in tankerCarsArray {
    print("This car is \(value.brandName)")
    print("The color is \(value.color)")
    print("The car has \(value.numberOfDoors) doors")
    print("The year of creation is \(value.yearOfCreation)")
    print("The tanker is filled with \(value.tankerFilledSize) lb of oil.")

    if value.tankerForm == .cilindrical {
        print("This car has cilindrical tanker form.")
    } else {
        print("This car has quadratic tanker form.")
    }
    print(" ")
}
```

Now the question. Is there any way to print all the properties for different classes? I tried to create a new array of three arrays:

```
var allClassesArrays = [carrsArray, sportCarsArray, tankerCarsArray]
```

But during iteration, it was able to get all the properties of the parent class.

Comment: Perhaps use Mirror? [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror)

Comment: You could iterate through `carrsArray + sportCarsArray + tankerCarsArray` (using `map` to upcast `[SportsCar]` and `[TankerCar] ` to `[Car]` if necessary, idr), but your element type during iteration would be `Car`. If you want `SportsCar` and `TankerCar` specific properties, you would need to downcast in the loop bodyy.

Comment: An alternative solution is to make `Car: CustomStringConvertible`, and have every `Car` subclass define how it converts itself to string. Then in your loop, you just access the `description`, and have the dynamic dispatch automatically resolve the correct conversion for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what reflection is for. You can add a property / method to the `Car` class that list all the properties of the current class, plus those of the superclass. When this property / method is dynamically applied to the subclasses, it will give what you are looking for.

We need an extension to `Mirror` that returns all properties of the current instance and those of its superclass recursively, taken from [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900936/2538939):

```
extension Mirror {
    func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
        var dict = [String: Any]()

        // Attributes of this class
        for attr in self.children {
            if let propertyName = attr.label {
                dict[propertyName] = attr.value
            }
        }

        // Attributes of superclass
        if let superclass = self.superclassMirror {
            for (propertyName, value) in superclass.toDictionary() {
                dict[propertyName] = value
            }
        }

        return dict
    }
}

class Car: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    // ...

    var debugDescription: String {
        let dict = Mirror(reflecting: self).toDictionary()
        return dict.map { "\($0.key) = \($0.value)" }.joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var allClassesArrays = [carrsArray, sportCarsArray, tankerCarsArray]
for car in allClassesArrays.flatMap({ $0 }) {
    print(car.debugDescription, terminator: "\n\n")
}
```

You of course don't have to conform `Car` to `CustomDebugStringConvertible` or name the property `debugDescription`. I just find them convenient since the debugger will use the `debugDescription` when you type `po car`.